# Почему здесь прибавляют 1?

Tags: java, массивы, пузырьковая-сортировка

Добрый день не могу разобраться с кодом почему к  переменной in добавляют 1

```
public void bubbleSorter(){     
for (int out = elems - 1; out >= 1; out--){  
        for (int in = 0; in < out; in++){      
            if(a[in] > a[in + 1])              
                toSwap(in, in + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Сравнивают (и в случае чего - меняют местами) два соседних элементах. Их индексы отличаются на 1. Вот этот один и прибавляют.

Answer (score 0):

Хотя код приведён не полностью (отсутствует toSwap), очевидно, что это реализация алгоритма сортировки методом пузырька, причем сортировки по возрастанию. Алгоритм проходит массив от начала и до конца, сравнивая попарно соседние элементы, Если элементы стоят в неправильном порядке, то они меняются местами, таким образом, после первого прохода на конце массива оказывается максимальный элемент.  Затем проход массива повторяется, и на предпоследнем месте оказывается другой наибольший после максимального элемент и т.д. В итоге наименьший элемент постепенно перемещается  к началу массива («всплывает» до нужной позиции как пузырёк в воде).

```js
public static void bubbleSort(int[] arr){
    /* Внешний цикл каждый раз сокращает фрагмент массива, 
      так как внутренний цикл каждый раз ставит в конец
      фрагмента максимальный элемент */   
    for(int i = arr.length-1 ; i > 0 ; i--){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++){
            /*Сравниваем элементы попарно, 
              если они имеют неправильный порядок, 
              то меняем местами
            if( arr[j] > arr[j+1] ){
                int tmp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```